# how to create Multiple layers?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'd like to create multiple layers for asset management using openlayers, could anybody help?

Comment: Could you specify your problem?

Comment: more details please...

Answer (score 2):

Openlayers site has many useful examples which allow you to start work. Start with that and ask question specifically what is the issue. 
Here examples: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/
Few useful ones: 
            http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/all-overlays-google.html
            http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html